# programming in vi

Tags: vi

Is it possible to use vi/vim commands to write the number 1-10 on separate lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:call append('.', range(1, 10))
```

Comment: how do i learn more about this? what would i search for in google?

Answer (score 0):

You will get a list of functions using `:help functions` if ViM is installed correctly. Additionally you should read `:help script`, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run vi scripts using the -s option on vi, i.e.

vi -s scriptname filename